# Selecting favourites from DB rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a small app which has Users, Recipes, Ingredients and preparation models

A user has many recipes, recipes belong to user and ingredients/preparation belongs to recipes.

Now a user can view all recipes but I would like the option to add the particular recipe to a favourites list. Would I need to set a new DB to hold this and then link by associations or could I add a column to the recipe model called fav for example?

Im looking for the best practice here or if someone has done this before and can offer any advice that would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set `has_may` association like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :favorite_recipes, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "Recipe", dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: so create seperate table for favourite_recipes?

Comment: No, you don't need, i don't know how to explain idea for you but you can check here for example [Follower and Following](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top). In this example, user have following and followers users, in your case, user will have recipes and favorites recipes, i think you can do like that example. Hope this help for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a boolean column `favorited` to your UsersRecipe table.

Then you can add a scope for this in your `User` model:

```
has_many :favorite_recipes, :through => :user_recipes, :class => Recipe, :conditions => ['user_recipes.favorited = ?',true]
```

Comment: not sure i understand sorry, do you mean add favorited column to my recipe model?

Comment: Yes, you could add a favorited column to your recipe model. I think Kien's answer is interesting as well.